# How to locate a list of webelement using Css selector in C#

Tags: c#, css, selenium

I am trying to locate a list of "x-tree-node" webelement from the following HTML page.

```
<div class = "x-tree-root-node"> </div>
  <li class = "x-tree-node"> </li>
    <ul class = "x-tree-node-ct"> </ul>
      <li class = "x-tree-node"> </li> #Starts from here, those elements are the list of 'x-tree-node' I want to find.
      <li class = "x-tree-node"> </li> #I want this to be found in my list.
      <li class = "x-tree-node"> </li> #I want this to be found in my list.
      <li class = "x-tree-node"> </li> #I want this to be found in my list.
```

The code I am using is:

```
    public By TopLevelNodeLocator {
        get { return By.CssSelector(".x-tree-root-node.x-tree-node.x-tree-node-ct.x-tree-node");  }
    }

    public IList<IWebElement> AllTopLevelNode {
        get { return WebDriver.FindElements(TopLevelNodeLocator);  }
    }
```

But the IList I get returned an timeout exception, which means nothing has been found.

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: The sample HTML is confusing. Are the `x-tree-node` children of `x-tree-node-ct` which is a child of `x-tree-node` which is a child of `x-tree-root-node`?

Comment: So I know I am understanding the question correctly, you are looking for a list of all the `<li>` elements with the class `"x-tree-node"`, and nothing else? Or are you looking for all elements with the class containing `"x-tree"`?

Comment: @ bagelmakers, you are right, all I am looking for is '<li> x-tree-node-ct </li> ' elements that are grand grand children of '<div> x-tree-root-node </div>'. I have to say my original HTML elements is bit confusing. Please see the updated version. There are more than one '<li> x-tree-node-ct </li> ' as the grand grand children of '<div> x-tree-root-node </div>'.

Comment: @Arran, I apologize for this confusion, I will update my HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
By.CssSelector(".x-tree-node")
```

if you just want the elements that are children of the unordered list:

```
By.CssSelector(".x-tree-node-ct .x-tree-node")
```

or

```
By.CssSelector(".x-tree-node-ct > .x-tree-node")
```

or

```
By.CssSelector("ul .x-tree-node")
```

or

```
By.CssSelector("ul > .x-tree-node")
```

There are a bunch of ways you can do this.

Your property name of TopLevelNodeLocator makes it sound like you are trying to locate the root node, though, just fyi.